# How to publish only one message using a Java MQTT client using Eclipse Paho

Tags: java, android, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I'm doing a project for my final University work.
I want do a android app that comunicates with my raspberry pi using MQTT protocol.
To do it I'm using a mosquitto broker, but when I publish message in a broker using the  Java MQTT client using Eclipse Paho, my app publish the same message 5 times, and I don't know if the fault is of my class that publish message, or of my class on_create() of android.

My code is the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements    View.OnClickListener {
EditText distanceCondition;
EditText timeCondition;
EditText countCondition;

String distance;
String time;
String count;
String topic;

int notificationID = 1;
int functionality;
int ok = 1;

public void mqttconnect(final String topic, final String message){

    final MqttAndroidClient mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), "tcp://192.168.1.36", "androidSampleClient");
    mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {                                      //iot.eclipse.org:1883
        @Override
        public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
            System.out.println("Connection was lost!");

        }

        @Override
        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Message Arrived!: " + topic + ": " + new String(message.getPayload()));
            //displayNotification("DETECT MOVEMENT! visit LCESS app now.");
            JSONObject inf = new JSONObject(Arrays.toString(message.getPayload()));
            try {
                if (inf.optString("Functionality").equals(6)) {
                    if (inf.optString("ok").equals(1)) {
                        displayNotification("DETECT MOVEMENT! visit LCESS app now.");
                    }
                }
                if (inf.optString("Functionality").equals(7)) {
                    if (inf.optString("ok").equals(1)) {
                        displayNotification("DETECT MOVEMENT IN" + inf.optString("Distance") + " CM! visit LCESS app now.");
                    }
                }
                if (inf.optString("Functionality").equals(8)) {
                    if (inf.optString("ok").equals(1)) {
                        displayNotification("DETECT MOVEMENT IN" + inf.optString("Time") + " HOURS! visit LCESS app now.");
                    }
                }
                if (inf.optString("Functionality").equals(9)) {
                    if (inf.optString("ok").equals(1)) {
                        displayNotification("DETECT MOVEMENT IN" + inf.optString("Distance") + " CM and in " + inf.optString("Time") + " HOURS! visit LCESS app now.");
                    }
                }
                if (inf.optString("Functionality").equals(10)) {
                    if (inf.optString("ok").equals(1)) {
                        displayNotification("DETECT " + inf.optString("Count") + " OBJECTS/PERSONS! visit LCESS app now.");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception functionality){

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
            System.out.println("Delivery Complete!");
        }
    });

    try {
        mqttAndroidClient.connect(null, new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                System.out.println("Connection Success!");
                try {
                    System.out.println("Subscribing to: "+ topic);
                    mqttAndroidClient.subscribe(topic, 0);
                    System.out.println("Subscribed to: "+ topic);
                    System.out.println("Publishing message..");
                    mqttAndroidClient.publish(topic, new MqttMessage(message.getBytes()));
                } catch (MqttException ex) {
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                System.out.println("Connection Failure!");
            }
        });
    } catch (MqttException ex) {

    }


}

public JSONObject sendJSONmessage() {
    topic = "Mesurement";
    distance = distanceCondition.getText().toString();
    time = timeCondition.getText().toString();
    count = countCondition.getText().toString();

    JSONObject post_dict = new JSONObject();
    try {
        post_dict.put("Topic", topic);
        post_dict.put("ok" ,ok);
        post_dict.put("Functionality", functionality);
        post_dict.put("Distance", distance);
        post_dict.put("Time", time);
        post_dict.put("Count", count);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (post_dict.length() > 0) {
        System.out.println(post_dict);
    }
    return post_dict;
}

protected void displayNotification(CharSequence contentText){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("notificationID", notificationID);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    CharSequence ticker ="Notification in LCESS";
    CharSequence contentTitle = "LCESS";

    Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setTicker(ticker)
            .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
            .setContentText(contentText)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.lcess)
            .addAction(R.drawable.lcess, ticker, pendingIntent)
            .setVibrate(new long[] {100, 250, 100, 500})
            .build();
    nm.notify(notificationID, noti);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    distanceCondition = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_detectDistanceCondition);
    timeCondition = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_detectTimeCondition);
    countCondition = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_countDetects);

    Button button_detectDistance = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_detectDistance);
    Button button_detectDistanceCondition = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_detectDistanceCondition);
    Button button_detectTimeCondition = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_detectTimeCondition);
    Button button_detectIfAllCondition = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_detectIfAllCondition);
    Button button_count = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_count);
    assert button_detectDistance != null;
    /*button_detectDistance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            functionality = 1;
            mqttconnect("Device1/Detect", sendJSONmessage().toString());
        }
    });*/
    button_detectDistance.setOnClickListener(this);
    assert button_detectDistanceCondition != null;
    button_detectDistanceCondition.setOnClickListener(this);
    assert button_detectTimeCondition != null;
    button_detectTimeCondition.setOnClickListener(this);
    assert button_detectIfAllCondition != null;
    button_detectIfAllCondition.setOnClickListener(this);
    assert button_count != null;
    button_count.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v){
    if (R.id.button_detectDistance==v.getId()){
        functionality = 1;
        mqttconnect("Mesurement", sendJSONmessage().toString());
    }
    else if (R.id.button_detectDistanceCondition==v.getId()){
        functionality = 2;
        mqttconnect(sendJSONmessage().optString(topic), sendJSONmessage().toString());
    }
    else if (R.id.button_detectTimeCondition==v.getId()){
        functionality = 3;
        mqttconnect(sendJSONmessage().optString(topic), sendJSONmessage().toString());
    }
    else if (R.id.button_detectIfAllCondition==v.getId()){
        functionality = 4;
        mqttconnect("Device1/Detect1", sendJSONmessage().toString());
    }
    else if (R.id.button_count==v.getId()){
        functionality = 5;
        mqttconnect("Device1/Detect1", sendJSONmessage().toString());
    }
}
```

}

First, I created the Mqtt class to publish and subscribe to the topic, After, the class to publish the message that I need in JSON format.

The next class I use it to display a notification.
And finally, onCreate() and onClick classes where I declared my buttons, edittext... And where I put the conditions to publish a message. 
More concretly, when push a button, I publish a message in a topic with JSON format.

The App run well. But the question is:
How I can publish ONLY one message in a broker?

In the following picture you can see how publish 5 message when I press the button.
[In red you can see the message published 5 or 6 times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwiWD.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem.
In this case how I build a function to connect with the broker,  each time that I click some buttom I publish and subscribe again to the topic. and only I have to subscribe  one time.
The solution is connect to the broken and subscribe to the topic, only one time, thus we implement the same code but in onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
String msg = "{\"uuid\":\"12345678\"}";
MqttMessage m = new MqttMessage();
m.setPayload(msg.getBytes());
m.setQos(2);
m.setRetained(false);
mqttAndroidClient.publish(topic, m);
```